# How to type ASCII HEX 88 character on ubuntu terminal for a buffer overflow?

Tags: terminal

I am trying to perform a buffer overflow on an interactive C program. I have to rewrite the EIP with an address which has hex value 88 as one byte. For that I have to type the corresponding ASCII when prompted.

I tried **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **u** and entered the hex value [**u88**] to get the character, but it didn't work. Instead it sent **C288** to the register.

I did some research and figured out that it is **Character Tabulation Set [HTS]** however I was unable to find an escape encoding which would work on Ubuntu.

- ***PS:*** Perl or python to pass **\x88** is not an option here as the
  program doesn't take the user input via arguments.

Comment: If it reads from stdin you can pipe it into the program with `echo -e "\x88" | ./a.out` otherwise if it is text based you can wrap it with `expect`

Comment: @wireghoul I can't pass that as an argument as I already have mentioned in the question. I am looking for an encoding method. Like Ctrl + @ for null character.

Comment: That's not passed as an argument; `echo` passes it to the program's STDIN.

Comment: Still won't work as it is an interactive program. Let's say that automating it is pretty difficult.

Comment: This is only typing a specific character in a terminal and is thus off-topic here. It does not matter if you need the character for a buffer overflow.

Comment: And you can't paste? And there are no other address with the same or equivalent gadget?

Comment: Terminals nowadays default to UTF-8 encoding, that's why Ctrl+Shift+U followed by 88 gets converted to U+0088's UTF-8 representation, which is 0xC2 0x88. In UTF-8 encoding there is no way you could send a single 0x88 byte, as that is not valid UTF-8. You need to switch your terminal's encoding to some old-fashioned 8-bit, preferably one where 0x88 is a printable character (unlike Latin-* encodings), and then you'll be able to paste it.

Comment: Or see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20386980/4457671 for how to inject an arbitrary byte sequence (not necessarily valid UTF-8) into the terminal as if it was input by the user.

Comment: @egmont Thank you! You are a life saver. I changed the encoding to Western (ISO-8859-1 and it worked.

Comment: You seem to be confused about ASCII.  There is no codepoint at 0x88 in ASCII (valid ASCII codepoints are 0x00 to 0x7f); perhaps you're interested in one of the ISO 8859 encodings?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes Toby. Egmont's suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the character encoding of the terminal and then I was able to enter the character by **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **U** and typing 88.

Terminal > Set Character Encoding

Select **Western (ISO-8859-1)**